# How to filter based on edge's property using GRANDstack

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo

How can I filter my results based on my edges props? 
For example: Getting user's new friends from 2 months ago.

```
type User {
   ...
   fiends(before: String) @relation(name: "FRIEND", direction: "OUT")
}

User {
   ...
   friends(before: '03.2018')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you can't ... you need to write your own resolver for that.

Can you open on the github project a new issue to ask for this new feature ?

Thanks.